# How to find the missing elements in a sequence?

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I have  a string arraylist  under that i need to pass **22184** elements from ["AA00001", "AA00005" ,"AA00003" ----- "ZZ00678"]  and i need to generate the sequence elements which are not present in the list. I have written code for that and for less inputs it is generating the required output. But when i am adding  22184 elements and want to generate 200 unique ids which are not present in the arraylist i am getting error as

**The code of method main(String[]) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit**

Can someone please help ?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenerateIds
{
    private static ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    static int n=50;  //no of Ids u want to generate
    static int completed =0;
    static char ID[] = new char[7];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ids.add("AA00001");
        ids.add("AA00004");
        ids.add("AA00007");
        generateIds(0);
        for(String id : ids)
        {
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }


    private static void generateIds(int i)
    {
        if(n!=completed)
        {
            if(i<2)
            {
                for(char c ='A';c<'Z';c++)
                {
                    ID[i]=c;
                    generateIds(i+1);
                }
            }
            else if(i>=2 && i<7)
            {
                for(char c ='0';c<='9';c++)
                {
                    ID[i]=c;
                    generateIds(i+1);
                }
            }else if(i==7)
            {
                String id = String.valueOf(ID);
                if(!ids.contains(id))
                {
                    ids.add(id);
                    completed++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code definitely does not exceed the 64k limit. It [runs fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/MwiiUQ).

Comment: You could put your id's in a text file, and read the text file.

Comment: If you're doing all the `ids.add("AA00001");
        ids.add("AA00004");
        ids.add("AA00007");... <many more>` in your main method, it easily exceeds the limit because it gets too big. It would be better to have an external file with all IDs and read that into your list.

Comment: I suppose the failing code has 22000+ statements like ```ids.add("...")```. If that's the case, have you considered putting this list of ids in a file and reading this instead of putting them in the source code?

Comment: That code compiles and run perfectly without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your id's in a text file. Then use something like.

```
List<String> ids = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("ids.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> In java a methods can't have more than 65535 bytes.

The main method is becoming too large since you are doing all the adds inline:

```
ids.add("AA00001");
ids.add("AA00004");
ids.add("AA00007");
...
```

This will make the main method too long. What you can do to solve this *(and to find the missing elements)* is putting all the String values in a List and loop over it to find the missing elements:

```
public void findMissingElements() {

    List<String> missingIds = allPossibleIds.stream()
                                            .filter(isMissingIn(existingIds))
                                            .collect(toList());

    //do something with the missingIds...

}
```

As other readers such as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067492/matt) suggested, you can e.g. put all the Strings in a file and read the file.

I wrote a small example to show how it would all work together. I rewrote your `generateIds` method with jOOλ to generate all the possible ids and renamed it to `allPossibleIds` (however your recursive method would work too). I limited the ids to a 3 size digit number to limit the search time as an example.

```
  public class FindMissingIdsTest {

  private List<String> allPossibleIds;
  private List<String> existingIds;

  @Before
  public void setup() throws IOException {
    allPossibleIds = allPossibleIds();
    existingIds    = retrieveIdsFromSubSystem();
  }

  @Test
  public void findMissingElements() {

    List<String> missingIds = allPossibleIds.stream()
                                            .filter(isMissingIn(existingIds))
                                            .collect(toList());

  }

  private Predicate<String> isMissingIn(List<String> existingIds) {
    return possibleId -> !existingIds.contains(possibleId);
  }

  public List<String> allPossibleIds(){
    List<String> alphabet = Seq.rangeClosed('A', 'Z').map(Object::toString).toList();
    List<String> letterCombinations = Seq.seq(alphabet).crossJoin(Seq.seq(alphabet)).map(t -> t.v1 + t.v2).toList();
    List<String> numbericParts = IntStream.range(0, 1000)
                                          .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%03d", i))
                                          .collect(toList());

    return Seq.seq(letterCombinations).crossJoin(Seq.seq(numbericParts)).map(t -> t.v1 + t.v2).toList();
  }

  public List<String> retrieveIdsFromSubSystem() throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("ids.txt"));
  }

}
```

To change to 5 digits again you can just change the 1000 to 100000 and the %03d to %05d.

If you can order the list, you could probably find a faster and better algorithm. It all depends on the situation. e.g. if you have an ordered list, you could build up the stream of all the ids, iterate over it and follow in the existing list with a pointer instead of always doing a resource consuming `contains()`.